# U-Boot Application that can access all files on USB Flash Drive

Tags: u-boot

I just started learning about U-Boot and being able to write applications that can be run with U-Boot, so please be patient and if possible add more details to help me learn.

I wanted to ask for help, as I am trying to connect USB flash drive to my Arm Cortex A9 device. I want to be able to have access to all files on that drive through my U-Boot script. For example My script/application (not sure what I'll be doing yet) will just run after U-Boot loads, and my script will parse through all files.

I plan to use a U-Boot application, so that I have access to all U-Boot drivers. U-boot supports USB, and I am able to see my USB Flash Drive on the U-boot command line. How can this be done, any help is HIGHLY appreciated please.

Comment: May I ask: Why are u using u-boot to parse the files?  U-boot is a boot loader primarily. Are the commands `fatinfo fatload fatls` and the ext equivalent `ext2load ext2ls` what you are looking for?

Comment: I want my system to just do a simple task quickly on bootup, don't have time  to wait for a linux or other OS to boot. And U-boot has capability to access USB flash drive, so I wanted to use that to mount the USB.

I am completely new to this field, and don't know much. I just saw that U-boot can have applications run by it, so I figured since it has what I need, if i can use U-boot commands to do my task, then I don't have to learn now to write an embedded systems program to access USB flash drive and stuff.

If I am on the wrong path, please do guide me.

Comment: Okay big question: "I want my system to just do a simple task quickly on bootup..." What kind of task? U-boot will allow you to load a binary into memory and jump to it, but the hardware support may not be as extensive. If your application needs access to device storage like USB and SD I think that your application would need to include code to access these devices. Even 'simple' things like memory management, and cpu co-processors might not work once u-boot is no longer running. Someone should double check this for the  Arm Cortex A9.

Comment: Using an OS like linux will give your application access to virtual memory, device storage, serial io, and what other drivers that linux has for you board. In addition it is relatively simple to write a bash script that can accomplish many things.
I have a simple, no GUI, linux for my board MX-233 that I add scripts to. This OS and device tree and u-boot boot loader is less than 16M and loads in seconds.

Comment: Here is some info to consider. [link](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162352/what-are-the-advantages-of-programming-to-under-an-os-as-opposed-to-bare-metal-e) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773480/in-embedded-design-what-is-the-actual-overhead-of-using-a-linux-os-vs-programmi) and [link](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/simplest-bare-metal-program-for-arm/)

Comment: Oh that sounds more practical. Using a no GUI Linux that boots very quickly. I would love to use this option. 

Let me look at the links and then get back to you. Thanks so much for pointing me to a better solution, it really means A LOT!

Comment: Where can I find a simple linux, no GUI, where I can just mount a USB flash drive, and then the host which is connected via Ethernet to my board, can send a command and access the content of the flash drive.  ahirapoc@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to collect information. (Please verify my answers)

- Your micro processor (µP) is an Arm Cortex A9.
- The instruction set your µP uses is: ARMv7-A 32bit.
- Who makes your board. Who is the vendor?
- What are some of the linux kernel groups for this board. You want one that is actively maintained.

Who is the board vendor. Each manufacturer or vendor could put the board together differently. The way the USB is connected. The type and size on memory (sd RAM?), etc .
 Examples Freescale, Samsung EM4412, or SoCKit. There are many.

Most board vendors have support. Most are not connected to the board vendor, but are supported by individuals. They should have a custom linux kernel and driver source for you to compile that matches you specific board. Using this method you have the ability to only include the bare minimum kernel modules, leading to a small OS or at the other end a full build with GUI and applications.

Once you get here now the fun begins. You will build your own development machine that includes a cross-compiler. This will allow you to cross-compile a small linux OS that works for you.

This method has a high learning curve, but is very rewarding at the end.

Vocabulary:

‘custom compile linux’ ‘cross-compiler for ARM’ ‘board support package’ ‘linux module’  ‘boot loader’

Comment: I have a Altera Cyclone V SOCKIT from Arrow.